# Edit function not working for my CRUD App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud, react-functional-component

I am building a simple CRUD app, and I have 90% of it working but for some reason I can't get the "edit" functionality to work. When I go to edit my team members name, nothing happens when I click "Edit Name". Worth noting, I copied the code from my "add user" component and modified were needed. Here is my code:

// EDIT USER

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap'

const EditUser = (props) => {
const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({
  id: '',
  name: ''
});
const { users, editUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const currentUserId = useParams(props);

useEffect(() => {
  const userId = currentUserId;
  const selectedUser = users.find((user) => user.id === userId);
  if (selectedUser) {
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
  } 
}, [currentUserId, users]);

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  editUser(selectedUser)
  navigate('/');
}

const onChange = (e) => {
  setSelectedUser({...selectedUser, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

  return (
    <div className='container w-25'>
        <Form className='form-control' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label>Edit Name</Label>
                <Input type='text' name='name' value={selectedUser.name} onChange={onChange} placeholder='Enter Name'></Input>
            </FormGroup>
        <Button type='submit'>Edit Name</Button>
        <Link to='/' className='btn btn-danger m-2'>Back</Link>
        </Form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EditUser
```

// ADD USER

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap'

const AddUser = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const { addUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const newUser = {
      id: uuid(),
      name: name
    }
    addUser(newUser);
    navigate('/');
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className='container w-25'>
        <Form className='form-control' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label>Name</Label>
                <Input 
                type='text' 
                name={name} 
                value={name} 
                onChange={onChange} 
                placeholder='Enter Name'></Input>
            </FormGroup>
        <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        <Link to='/' className='btn btn-danger m-2'>Back</Link>
        </Form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddUser
```

// GLOBAL CONTEXT

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer';

const initialState = {
        users: []
    };

// Create Context \\

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

// Provider Component \\

export const GlobalProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

    // Actions

    const removeUser = (id) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'REMOVE_USER',
            payload: id
        });
    }

    const addUser = (user) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_USER',
            payload: user
        });
    }

    const editUser = (user) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "EDIT_USER",
            payload: user
        });
    }

    return(
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{
            users: state.users,
            removeUser,
            addUser,
            editUser
        }}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

// APP REDUCER

```
export default (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'REMOVE_USER':
            return {
                users: state.users.filter(user => {
                    return user.id !== action.payload
                })
            }

            case 'ADD_USER':
                return {
                    users: [action.payload, ...state.users]
                }
            case 'EDIT_USER':
                const updateUser = action.payload
                const updateUsers = state.users.map(user => {
                    if(user.id === updateUser.id) {
                        return updateUser;
                    }
                    return user;
                })

                return {
                    users: updateUsers
                }
        
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify more clearly what isn't working? Is the `Input` not working? Or is the form submission not working? Something else?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the onChange or OnSubmit - the name doesn't change when the edit button is clicked.

Comment: So it sounds like the input field is changing, the local `selectedUser` state is updating, yes? It's only when the form is submitted and `selectedUser` is passed to `editUser` from the context? Can you share that context code so we can see what `editUser` does?

Comment: I can click the edit button and the text changes on screen but doesn't update when I click the "edit name" button. What context code are you looking for? Sorry, just a little confused. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue seems to be that the `Edit` component isn't accessing the route paths params object correctly, to reference the route path's `userId` param.

```
const currentUserId = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const userId = currentUserId;
  const selectedUser = users.find((user) => user.id === userId);
  if (selectedUser) {
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
  } 
}, [currentUserId, users]);
```

Here the entire params object is named `currentUserId`. In the `useEffect` hook callback this params object is assigned to a local variable `userId` and then used to find a matching user object in the `users` array. It's comparing a specific user's `id` property (*a string type*) to the entire params object (*an object type*). This OFC will never be equal and `selectedUser` is undefined and the local `selectedUser` state is never initialized to the user you are trying to edit.

## Solution

Either access into the params object to correctly access the specific parameter:

```
const currentUserId = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const userId = currentUserId;
  const selectedUser = users.find((user) => user.id === userId.userId);
  if (selectedUser) {
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
  } 
}, [currentUserId, users]);
```

Or just destructure the `userId` path param directly:

```
const { userId } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const selectedUser = users.find((user) => user.id === userId);
  if (selectedUser) {
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
  } 
}, [userId, users]);
```

### Suggestion

Initialize the `selectedUser` state directly. Use a `useEffect` hook to check if there is a user to edit and issue a back navigation if there is not one to edit.

```
const EditUser = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { userId } = useParams();
  const { users, editUser } = useGlobalContext(); // *

  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(
    users.find((user) => user.id === userId)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedUser) navigate(-1);
  }, [navigate, selectedUser]);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    editUser(selectedUser);
    navigate("/");
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedUser({ ...selectedUser, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container w-25">
      {selectedUser && (
        <Form className="form-control" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label>Edit Name</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={selectedUser.name}
              onChange={onChange}
              placeholder="Enter Name"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit">Edit Name</Button>
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger m-2">
            Back
          </Link>
        </Form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit edit-function-not-working-for-my-crud-app]

* Note: This was just a custom hook created for convenience in the context code:

```
const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext);
```

Comment: I get this error when trying your solution: 

./src/components/EditUser.js
  Line 9:  'useGlobalContext' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: @DavidFeudale Oh, sorry. I had created that custom hook as `const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext);`, but you could continue using `const { users, editUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);` in `EditUser` if desired.

Comment: I wanted to message you directly but don't know how. When you click edit, edit the name & then submit it just adds a new member - it doesn't edit the current one. I noticed the edit button now takes you to the "create member" page instead of edit, so I'm assuming that's why. Not sure where in the code that change was made. Sorry for pesterng you, you've been a lot of help!

Comment: @DavidFeudale Could you provide a *running* codesandbox of the code you are using that we could inspect? It's probably a minor/trivial issue.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-function-not-working-for-my-crud-app-forked-7y50bl?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @DavidFeudale The edit route you have is `path="/Edit/:id"` but the edit component is looking for a `userId` param. The `userId` param is undefined and so no user is matched. These need to agree. Either edit the route to use `userId`, e.g. `path="/Edit/:userId"` or edit the `EditUser` component to destructure `id`, e.g. `const { id } = useParams()` and `users.find((user) => user.id === id)` for the initial `selectedUser` state value.